# dart: polymer scaffold - drawer not closing after menu selection

Tags: polymer, core-elements

I am using core-scaffold, and in general it works nicely (mainly). When I drag the window smaller (desktop), the drawer hides and the hamburger menu button appears and is functional.  However, when I select an item in the menu/drawer, the drawer does not retract. Viewing my webpage on a phone is not satisfactory. But it does update the content correctly.

**Is there some CSS that I should add?**

I have tried importing core-animation, core-transition-pages which make no difference. A bit naive I think!

It can be seen on my (draft) webpage acsumama.com

thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the website that you reference acsumama.com, and adding the following  onclick event in the menu  link works

```
<a href="/dome" onclick="document.querySelector('paper-scaffold').togglePanel();"></a>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work directly (in the HTML, for some reason..) but I added it in Dart. Works fine. Cheers,Steve